# combination of min and if for dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

its my first question here..............

Que.:-
I have 100s of dates in column A. I want to record next Sunday on 1st day of any month.
in cell B1 I putted a formula `=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A:A)=1,DAY(A:A)=1),A:A)` then dragged it in B column, then I have got required dates and FALSE values.
then in C1 I used a formula `=MIN(B:B)` I get exact required date.

but I need it in a single formula so I applied a formula `=MIN(IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A:A)=1,DAY(A:A)=1),A:A))` but it did not work.

I am wondering if anyone help me get it in a single formula correctly.
thanks!
regards,
HR

Comment: I don't understand what you want when you write "*record next Sunday on 1st day of any month*".  Can you be more specific, and especially can you give examples of input and desired output -- by providing an example of the dates in column A, and where and what you want for output.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi "I meant to say that I need the date of first Sunday which comes on 1st day of a Month." for ex:1st March,2015
Thanks!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4yByr16j47mUEJNUF9jOC1ISWc/view?usp=sharing its my working, but formula on the cell D1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your `MIN(IF` function doesn't work is because you can't use `AND` in those type of formulas, because `AND` will return a single result not the required array - you can either use * to simulate `AND` or use nested IFs, e.g. either

`=MIN(IF((WEEKDAY(A:A)=1)*(DAY(A:A)=1),A:A))`

or

`=MIN(IF(WEEKDAY(A:A)=1,IF(DAY(A:A)=1,A:A)))`

.....but if you want to get the *next first of month Sunday* after any date in A2 you can use this non-array formula:

`=EOMONTH(A2,MATCH(1,WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13})+1),0)-1)+1`

There are never more than 14 months between instances so you can examine the next 14 first of month dates and take the first one that's a Sunday

Comment: * & IFs give same.
BTW EOMONTH's formula is great and simple

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the first Sunday after today that occurs on the first day of a month.  If that is the case, the following **array** formula will return that date:

```
=INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT(TODAY()&":"&TODAY()+1000)),MATCH(1,(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(TODAY()&":"&TODAY()+1000)))=1)*(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(TODAY()&":"&TODAY()+1000)))=1),0))
```

To enter an **array** formula, hold down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula which you can see in the formula bar.

This portion of the formula:

```
ROW(INDIRECT(TODAY()&":"&TODAY()+1000))
```

creates an array of dates starting with TODAY and extending forward for 1000 days.  I picked 1000 because I don't know the longest possible interval between  first Sundays on the 1st of a month. Empirically, there seem to be at least one per year, if not two, so a smaller number may be equally effective.

Comment: Thank you! you answered my query correctly.
and a more thing can't I solve it by "MIN(IF" logic in the cell D1 in uploaded sheet?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4yByr16j47mUEJNUF9jOC1ISWc/view